# Integral of a logarithm containing exponentials

Tags: definite-integrals, logarithms

I would like to know the exact expression for the following integral
$$
I_{p,q}=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}e^{ip\alpha}e^{iq\beta}ln\left|sin\left(\frac{\alpha-\beta}{2}\right)\right|d\alpha d\beta
$$
where $p$ and $q$ are integers. I can run individual integrals in Mathematica, but it won't do the general integral, even when I add the assumptions that $p$ and $q$ are integers. Some examples that the exact solution should be consistent with are:
$$
I_{0,0}=-4\pi^{2}ln(2)
$$
$$
I_{-1,1}=I_{1,-1}=-2\pi^{2}
$$
$$
I_{-2,2}=I_{2,-2}=-\pi^{2}
$$
and I think all integrals not of the form $I_{-q,q}$ vanish. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Would you mind changing the names of the variables? For example, the integers could be written as $p, q$, and the angles could be written as $\alpha, \beta$.

Comment: Probably,  If $p = -q = m$ and $m\neq 0$ then: $I_{p,-q}=I_m=-\frac{4 \pi ^2}{m}$